# require.js: how can I load a module that defines a name under a different name?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I'm trying to load `underscore.js` with `require.js` like this:

```
require(["libs/underscore-1.2.3.js"], function(_) {
    ...
});
```

But this doesn't work because `underscore.js` exports a module name: `define('underscore', function() { ... })`.

Without renaming `lib/underscore-1.2.3.js`, how can I load it with `require.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after some more googling, I've found: https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/pull/338#issuecomment-3245213

Where

> @dvdotsenko all AMD loaders allow mapping a module ID to a partial path, usually the configuration is called 'paths', so to do what you want:
>
> ```
>    requirejs.config({
>        paths:
>            underscore: 'js/libs/underscore-1.2.3.min'
>        }
>    });
>    require(['underscore'], function () {});
> ```
>
> Since underscore is used by other higher-level modules, like backbone, a common dependency name needs to be used to communicate a common dependency on underscore, and it makes sense to call that dependency 'underscore'. The paths config gives a way to do the mapping to a specific URL you want to use for that dependency.

This doesn't *answer* my question (ie, I still don't know how I'd go about loading underscore if all I had was a URL), but at least it's a functional workaround.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't strike me as the most ideal solution, you can require your external files, and then require their registered module names in the inner block.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BcZQ6/)

```
require(
    ['require','http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js'],
    function(require){
        require(['underscore'],function(_){
            var a = _.intersection([1,2,3],[2,3,4]);
            document.write("Underscore is available in the closure : " + a);
        })
    }
)
```

It might not look pretty, but that might be a recommended pattern for loading up initial assets so that they can be required intuitively in dependent modules.